# Optimization on table selected where primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, where

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_dev_posts, wp_dev_postmeta, wp_dev_term_relationships 
WHERE ((post_type = 'projects') OR (post_type = 'post_cost_codes')) 
    AND (wp_dev_posts.ID = wp_dev_postmeta.post_id) 
    AND (wp_dev_posts.ID = wp_dev_term_relationships.object_id);
```

My question, is that when I have this in the where:

```
wp_dev_posts.ID = wp_dev_term_relationships.object_id
```

What's the correct way to optimize this? Am I better to use joins? Do I set index's? Do I use foreign keys? On a large database this is actually take a few seconds to run.

SQL newbie here.

FYI, this is Wordpress, with 33k rows in posts, about 250k rows in postmeta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'd want to rewrite that query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_dev_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_dev_postmeta 
        ON wp_dev_posts.ID = wp_dev_postmeta.post_id
    INNER JOIN wp_dev_term_relationships 
        ON wp_dev_posts.ID = wp_dev_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE ((post_type = 'projects') OR (post_type = 'post_cost_codes'));
```

Notice, I've moved parts of the `WHERE` clause to the `FROM` clause, using the `ON` construct.  That makes the query easier to read.

To optimize access to the table, you'd generally like to have indexes on `wp_dev_posts.ID`, `wp_dev_postmeta.post_id`, `wp_dev_term_relationships.object_id`, and `post_type`.

It might make sense to create a compound index on `wp_dev_posts` for `(post_type, ID)`.

You'd *probably* want a foreign key on `wp_dev_postmeta` pointing to the primary key defined on `wp_dev_posts.ID`.

Providing more details about your specific environment, including the definition of the tables, any existing queries, row counts, etc, would help us provide a more definitive answer.